# Html file upload drag and drop not working

Tags: html

I am making a site where you can convert your file to a data URL. Here is my current code where you select the file:

```js
function convertToDataURL() {
  alert("convert to data url");
}
```

```css
.dropzone {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file" style="display: none" onchange="convertToDataURL()" />
<label for="fileInput">
  <div class="dropzone">Select or drop a file here</div>
</label>
```

The JavaScript works just fine, which is why I left it out. If I click the file input and select a file, the conversion successfully works. But if I drag a file to the file input, the input doesn't register the file, and the file just opens in a new tab. What is the cause of this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that a simple `<div>` with no backing JavaScript functionality would accept a file drop out of the box? Can you share the source upon which you're basing that implicit claim? Usually you need to include something like `dropzone.js` to get the functionality you need (or to implement it yourself).

Comment: The JS should be included.

Comment: Right, to put it simply, the standard `<input>` tag does not support drag-and-drop.  You have to load a module to do that.  The standard browser response to a dropped file is to open a new tab, as you have seen.

Comment: The div is inside a `<label for="fileInput">`. So if the label registers file input, shouldn't the label's children?

Comment: The raw `<input type="file">` registered file drag and drops.